# Prove that $P_1,\cdots,P_r$ are distinct prime ideals of $O_K$ with $<p>=P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r}$ and $N(P_i)=p^{deg f_i},i=1,2,\cdots,r$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $K=\Bbb Q(\theta)$ be an algebraic number field with $\theta \in O_K$. Let $p$ be a rational prime. Let $$f(x)=irr_{\Bbb Q}(\theta)\in \Bbb Z[x]$$

Let $\bar{}$ denote the natural map $:\Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z_p[x]$, where $\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z.$ Let 
$$\bar{f}(x)=g_1(x)^{e_1}\cdots g_r(x)^{e_r}$$ 
where $g_1(x),\cdots g_r(x)$ are distinct monic irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ and $e_1, \cdots , e_r$ are positive integers. For $i=1, \cdots,r$ let $f_i(x)$ be any monic polynomial of $\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $\bar{f_i}=g_i$. Set 
$$P_i=<p,f_i(\theta)>, i=1,2,\cdots,r$$.

If $ind(\theta) \not \equiv 0(\text{mod p})$ then $P_1,\cdots,P_r$ are distinct prime ideals of $O_K$ with 
$$<p>=P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r}$$ and 
$$N(P_i)=p^{deg f_i},i=1,2,\cdots,r$$
Here $ind(\theta)$ is the positive integer given by $D(\theta)=ind(\theta)^2d(K)$ where $D(\theta)$ and $d(K)$ are discriminant of $\theta$ and $K$ respectively.

**My attempt:** I have proved this one for $ind(\theta)=1$ i.e Let $K=\Bbb Q(\theta)$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$ s.t $$O_K=\Bbb Z+\Bbb Z\theta+\cdots +\Bbb Z\theta^{n-1}$$. 
Let $p$ be a rational prime. Let $$f(x)=irr_{\Bbb Q}(\theta)\in \Bbb Z[x]$$

Let $\bar{}$ denote the natural map $:\Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Z_p[x]$, where $\Bbb Z_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z.$ Let 
$$\bar{f}(x)=g_1(x)^{e_1}\cdots g_r(x)^{e_r}$$ 
where $g_1(x),\cdots g_r(x)$ are distinct monic irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ and $e_1, \cdots , e_r$ are positive integers. For $i=1, \cdots,r$ let $f_i(x)$ be any monic polynomial of $\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $\bar{f_i}=g_i$. Set 
$$P_i=<p,f_i(\theta)>, i=1,2,\cdots,r.$$

Then $P_1,\cdots,P_r$ are distinct prime ideals of $O_K$ with 
$$<p>=P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r}$$ and 
$$N(P_i)=p^{deg f_i},i=1,2,\cdots,r$$

Comment: I believe exactly this theorem is proven in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory. It is Proposition (8.3) in Chapter 8 on Extensions of Dedekind Domains.